# How do I check both rendering :new and JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I try to add RSpec test for invalid entry `create` controller action, which responds to `HTTP` POST verb.

```
  it "case of invalid entry" do
      program=FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:program, :faculty_id => faculty.id, :code=>"воруй&убивай")
      post :create, {:program=>program, :faculty_shortcut=>faculty }
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end
```

Controller:

```
 if @program.save
    redirect_to faculty_program_path(faculty, @program)
    else
      render :new,:json => @program.errors
    end
```

What I get from RSpec

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:new)
       expecting <"new"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the record has been saved and you have been redirected. If you want to check behaviour when invalid data is passed, do not rely on existing validations as they might change in the future. Just stub `valid?` method:

```
it "case of invalid entry" do
      program=FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:program)
      allow_any_instance_of(Program).to receive(:valid?).and_return false
      post :create, {:program=>program, :faculty_shortcut=>faculty }
      expect(response).to render_template(:new)
    end
```

Stubbing `valid?` has this advantage that your test will not change when you change your validations. Validations on their own should be tested within model tests, this way single change in the code won't cause multiple test fails.

Comment: The reason that was bothering me is if test fails because of  `render :new,:json => @program.errors`. Not sure if test fails because code is wrong, or because,as failure reports says, RSpec doesn't expect an array (how do I declare it in test then?)

Comment: The error you got means nothing has been rendered. It is a common thing when your controller redirects or there was unhandled exception. On top of that your code for render is incorrect. You either specify the view to render or give it json object, you can to do both. If you want to fork depending on request format, use `respond_to`.